# How to style a list under div class in css?

Tags: css

Im very new to html and css, and I am having trouble accessing this list to edit in css:

```
  <div id="content">
    <div id="recent-users">
      <ul id="recent-user-list">
         <li class="user"><a href="#">Bob Bobalooba</a></li>
         <li class="user"><a href="#">Mary Contrary</a></li>
         <li class="user"><a href="#">James Bean</a></li>
         <li class="user"><a href="#">Jim Jimbulator</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
```

I've tried many variations of things like #recent-users-list, #content #recent-users #recent-users-list li a   etc and I havent been able to find any other posts that have helped witht his specific situation.

Thankyou in advance for any help.

Comment: Try using `#content>#recent-users>#recent-user-list>li`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, accessing elements via ids are done with hash `#` and classes with period `.`. They are not interchangeably.
You are not using commas to select underlying elements. Commas actually allow you to select multiple different elements at once.

You can directly access the list via:

```
#recent-user-list
```

Or its children `li` elements via:

```
#recent-user-list .user
```

Or its grandchildren `li a` elements via:

```
#recent-user-list .user a
```

Documentation can be found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp